Application of Inclusion Exclusion Principle
If you have $n$ indistinguishable balls which are randomly placed in one of $r$ distinguishable cells, with $ n \geq r $. Let $ U_i $ be the event that cell $ i $ is empty.
$$
\Pr(U_i) = \left( \frac{r-1}{r} \right)^n, \quad i = 1, \ldots, r
$$
$$
\Pr(U_i U_j) = \left( \frac{r-2}{r} \right)^n \quad \text{for } 1 \leq i < j \leq r, \ldots
$$
Poincaré’s theorem gives the probability of at least one empty cell as:
$$
\Pr(\text{at least one empty cell}) = 1 - \Pr(U_1 \cap U_2 \cap \ldots \cap U_r) = r^{-n} \sum_{i=1}^{r} (-1)^{i+1} \binom{r}{i} \left( \frac{r-i}{r} \right)^n
$$
noting that $ \Pr(U_1 \cap U_2 \cap \ldots \cap U_r) = 0 $.
I am wondering why $\binom{r}{i}$ enters the inclusion/exclsuion, given that $Pr(U_i)$ does not contain it. Can anyone see it?
Edit: My confusion stems from the fact that I am familiar with:
$$\Pr(A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Pr(A_i) - \sum_{i<j} \Pr(A_i \cap A_j) + \sum_{i<j<k} \Pr(A_i A_j A_k) - \cdots + (-1)^{n+1} \Pr(A_1 A_2 \cdots A_n)
$$
I guess it has to do with the independence of that events?
